# Rails 4.1: Can't generate controller, get 'bundle install' error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4

So I am trying to add facebook authentication with omniauth and noticed that I cannot generate a controller using

```
rails generate controller Sessions new create destroy
```

because I get the following error message:

```
Could not find bootstrap-sass-3.2.0.2 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

I have tried uninstalling and re-installing the gem with different versions, runding bundle update, etc. with no success. 
I am running rails 4.1.5 and using ruby 2.1.2.
Here is the current line in my gemfile:

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.2.0
```

I am in the app's directory, and have tried running command with bundle exec, but with no change.

Comment: what do you get after bundle install? Does it install bootstrap-sass for you?

Comment: Bundle install runs successfully, as does bundle update, and I have the correct gem and version.

Answer (score 1):

Not enough cred to make this a comment... but your gem line looks like it's missing a single quote.  Should be:

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.2.0'
```

Answer (score 1):

You may need to kill all the springs:

```
myapp swards$ ps aux | grep spring

swards     46617   0.1  0.3  2478996  22112   ??  Ss    1:27AM   0:00.57 spring app    | my-app | started 2 mins ago | development mode    
swards     46632   0.0  0.0  2442000    648 s002  S+    1:30AM   0:00.00 grep spring
swards     45116   0.0  0.2  2504588  15332 s002  S    10:55PM   0:00.30 spring server | my-app | started 2 hours ago   

myapp swards$ kill 46617 
myapp swards$ kill 45116
```

Answer (score 0):

Run the command with [bundle exec](http://bundler.io/v1.1/bundle_exec.html):

```
bundle exec rails generate controller Sessions new create destroy
```

This will ensure that all your bundled gems are available to Rails.

Comment: Should have added that I've tried with bundle exec, and with no change. I'll edit now.